# Binding Itemscontrol in Listbox

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-8

I want to binding my itemscontrol in listbox, but it doesn't work. I want to add some FrameworkElement to Listbox with stack style.

Here is my XAML code:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listThemes">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Margin="5">
                        <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" >
                                <ItemsControl  Width="Auto"
                                               Height="Auto"
                                               ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=listThemes, Path=Items}">
                                </ItemsControl>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I don't know how to binding ItemsControl inside ListBox. I try put out the Binding ElementName of ItemsControl but it's always crashes. If the ElementName is page name, it not work.

Testing Class :

```
public class Testing
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<FrameworkElement> Items { get; set; }
}
```

C# Code :

```
        observableCollection = new ObservableCollection<FrameworkElement>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            observableCollection.Add(new Button { Content = i.ToString() });
            observableCollection.Add(new Canvas
            {
                Background = new ImageBrush()
                {
                    ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Assets/ApplicationIcon.png", UriKind.Relative)),
                    Stretch = System.Windows.Media.Stretch.Fill
                },
                Height = 100,
                Width = 100
            });
        }

        List<Testing> list = new List<Testing>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            Testing test = new Testing();
            test.Title = "Testing";
            test.Items = observableCollection;

            list.Add(test);
        }

        listThemes.ItemsSource = list;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it crashes because you bind the same elements on three different item. One framework element can't be attach under two different control. So you should place your `ObservableCollection` in your `List<Testing>` creating process.

Second, you should set a `DataContext` to your `listThemes` control, so its items can find the right data path to bind and then you could remove the `ElementName`.

Try these code.

```
List<Testing> list = new List<Testing>();
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    Testing test = new Testing();
    test.Title = "Testing";

    var observableCollection = new ObservableCollection<FrameworkElement>();

    for (int j = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        observableCollection.Add(new Button { Content = j.ToString() });
        observableCollection.Add(new Canvas
        {
            Background = new ImageBrush()
            {
                ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Assets/ApplicationIcon.png", UriKind.Relative)),
                Stretch = System.Windows.Media.Stretch.Fill
            },
            Height = 100,
            Width = 100
        });
    }

    test.Items = observableCollection;

    list.Add(test);
}

listThemes.DataContext = list;
listThemes.ItemsSource = list;
```

Third, I don't think it is a good way to bind your `FrameworkElement` directly to an `ItemsControl`. It just look weird.

Update:

If you want to generate different types of items, you can use `DataTemplateSelector`. Because you already parse the forum data into different type, so please check this post:

[How to Control the DataTemplateSelector in Windows Store Apps](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bryanbolling/archive/2012/12/08/how-to-control-the-datatemplateselector-in-windows-store-apps.aspx)

It explains how to use `DataTemplateSelector` to display different type of data.

Comment: I want to add some canvas, textblock, button, ... to my stackpanel in my C# code. I dont know how to do it. Can you help me ?

Comment: @steven2211 If you want a non-dynamic template setting, you can just place the canvas, textblock, button things in Listbox Itemtemplate. Then binding the right data to each item.

Comment: I just wanna add some image, textblock, hyperlink button after the TextBlock. But in some situation, the image is above textblock, hyperlink. In another situation, the textblock is above hyperblink, image.
Example: 
>> Situation 1: Textblock (Fixed one) - Image - TextBlock - Image - Image - Image - Textblock - Hyperblink.
>> Situation 2: Textblock (Fixed one) - TextBlock - Image - TextBlock - TextBlock - Image - Hyperlink - Image - TextBlock.

----- I want to parse forum user post. The post maybe have Image, Hyperlink, Text, ...

Thank you

Comment: If I use DataTemplateSelector, it can use in some situation. But what I need is something can use in all situation.

Answer (score 0):

Why is your inner collection of type `FrameworkElement`?
Create a custom type for it and set an ItemTemplate for your inner ItemsControl.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key=NestedItemsTemplate>
    ....
</DataTemplate>


<ListBox x:Name="listThemes"
         ItemsSource="{Binding TestItems}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="5">
                    <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" >
                            <ItemsControl 
                                Width="Auto" Height="Auto"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=listThemes, Path=Items}"
                                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource NestedItemsTemplate}">
                            </ItemsControl>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: I want to add some canvas, textblock, button, ... to my stackpanel in my C# code. I dont know how to do it. Can you help me ?

Comment: Is there any specific reason you must do it in code-behind? XAML is the UI language and works better. I could help if you actually described what you wanna do. Adding a couple of controls on a stackpanel doesn't say anything.

Comment: I just wanna add some image, textblock, hyperlink button after the TextBlock. But in some situation, the image is above textblock, hyperlink. In another situation, the textblock is above hyperblink, image.
Example: 
>> Situation 1: Textblock (Fixed one) - Image - TextBlock - Image - Image - Image - Textblock - Hyperblink.
>> Situation 2: Textblock (Fixed one) - TextBlock - Image - TextBlock - TextBlock - Image - Hyperlink - Image - TextBlock.

----- I want to parse forum user post. The post maybe have Image, Hyperlink, Text, ...

Thank you